Do you see anything wrong with my power circuit?
As the battery input I am using a Turnigy Nano-Tech 2200mAh 3S 25C Lipo Pack w/XT60 that fully charged is able to provide 12.6V. The ferrite bead FB1(2744555576 from fair-rite) is supposed to act as a low pass filter, but I don't know if it's necessary in my design. The output of the first buck converter(LMR51430XFDDCR U5) is supposed to be 5V at 2.6A max. That output than goes into the other buck converter from where I am expecting 3.3V at 0.6A max. The parts that I used are:

LMR51430XFDDCR 5V at 2.6A:



Reference
Part




R8
CRCW040222K1FKED


R7
CRCW0402162KFKED


C25
GRM32ER61C476KE15L


C20
GRM188R71H104KA93D


L3
SRR1208-6R5ML


C23
GRM155R71C104KA88D


C19
C1608X7R1V105K080AC


U6
LMR51430XFDDCR




LMR51430XFDDCR 3.3V at 0.6A:



Reference
Part




R6
CRCW040222K1FKED


R5
CRCW0402100KFKED


C18
GRM1555C1H390JA01D


C21
C0805C106K8PACTU


C15
GRM188R71H104KA93D


L2
SRP1270-100M


C17
GRM155R71C104KA88D


C13
GRM188R71A225KE15D


U3
LMR51430XFDDCR





Most of the design and the parts should be alright since I used WEBENCH POWER DESIGNER. Any insight or recommendation is helpful!

The updated C18 placement after a comment:


Don't you want C18 across the100k resistor as a feedforward cap?  I think you'll be unhappy about a cap from the switch node to the feedback pin.

What is the purpose of C18? We don't know why you have chosen these parts. We would need to replicate the design and we could end up with same or different components, and we still know how you ended up with them. Schematic review questions without any specifics other than "does it look good" can be answered it "maybe, but will it work, who knows".

@JohnD I checked again and you are right, thanks for the help!

@JohnD I put a screenshot with the updated C18 placement

Looks OK now.  L2 looks oversized for 0.6 A, but you'd want at least a 7 A inductor to be sure you survive short-circuit so it will work fine.

As @jsotola says, it would be much easier on people if your parts list was formatted properly, and the part numbers were live links to the datasheets; just something to keep in mind for future questions.

@jsotola sorry for that! I just realized how it looks after you pointed it out, I listed every part one under the other, but it seems the post rearranged by itself.

@JohnD I will list the parts properly next time, thank you again for the insight!

@Justme to be completely honest I search in the datasheet for the LMR51430 and I couldn't find C18(Cff) nowhere also, but the schematic was made by WEBENCH POWER DESIGNER from the official TI site, so I think the schematic has to be OK? From what I have seen from other buck regulators from TI I think C18 is just a feedforward cap.

@jsotola I just edited the post. Thanks!

@Robert I made a further edit to include markdown for Table Support, to try and improve readability.

@Robert upvote for the effort to make your post presentable

Suggestions:  (1) Add resistor (100 to 1K) between SMPS EN input pins and each Vin rather than directly connected.  This allows adaptation when requirements change to require disabling one or both outputs and helps the PCB layout person recognize this is not the high-current path into the SMPS controller. (2) Rename +12V net to 12V_BATT to emphasize the input is not regulated, after the FB name becomes 12V_BATT_FILT .  (3) Add large zero Ohm jumper (maybe 0805 package) between first SMPS output (+5V) and second SMPS input so that you can measure the current into the second during testing.
